# Infinispan 11.x - 12.x Clear a RemoteCache Limiting Notification for Listeners

Tags: caching, listener, delete-row, infinispan

I have an Infinispan `RemoteCache` in a microservice **A** which is responsible of inserting/deleting entries inside it.

There is a microservice **B** which is subscribed to that `RemoteCache` (replicated entirely locally) that has a listener to catch entry-level operations, such as inserts or deletes, to mentain its local copy updated.

**I was wondering if there is a way to catch from the **B** listener if a `clear()` operation happened on the `RemoteCache` map. I was not able to find anything in the documentation.**

This is because, if the `RemoteCache` has a lot of entries, and **A** calls a `clear()` on it, I'd not like to receive each single notification and then perform a delete operation for each single entry in the **B** local cache. I'd rather to call the `clear()` method for the **B** local copy directly, instead.

Thank you in advance for your help (my "question" is in **bold**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no clear event.

I'm not sure why you need a local copy of data in **B** but, the hot rod client has a near-cache which caches locally the most accessed keys.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's due to a very strict performance constraint.